# Elasticsearch dies after too many queries from Python library

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I recently upgraded my Elasticsearch instance from 1 to 5, and I upgraded the python libraries (elasticsearch and elasticsearch-dsl) from 1 to 5 as well.

I have a script that will create an index and then populate it by creating documents from a relational database. The index is created, and the documents are added to the index, but after a couple of thousand of documents are added, I start to get these messages and my Elasticsearch instance goes down.

> ConnectionError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker_es_instance', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /items/sporting_goods/2378/_create (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)))

I assume that there are too many open connections, and that it is DOSing my Elasticsearch instance, but I am having trouble figuring out a solution.

Comment: check your index thread pool size. Also post your elasticsearch logs. Most probably you should be seeing GC error.

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [bulk helper](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html) from the Python library. This should be much faster, and solve your error.

Comment: I tried using bulk help too. The same problem occurred.